# Eclipse/Java - JDK Compliance

Tags: java, eclipse

This may seem a daft question so I will be as brief as possible.

Where I work, we deal with lots of Java apps that are compiled on old versions of Java, in fact we recently upgraded one of them to Java 1.6

We've been given new laptops recently with no admin rights and Java 7 installed by default.

I am presently unable to get hold of and install a copy of JDK 1.5 (which I need)

In Eclipse, if I set my JDK Compliance level to 1.5 but the Installed JRE is 1.7

Which of these 2 statements is true... ?

**1. I am building my code at Java 1.5 ?

 2. I am building my code at Java 7 ?**

I've seen and spoken to various people on this subject and I am still non-the-wiser.

Comment: No non-JDK 1.5 bytecode will be emitted. Not much of a mystery, really.

Comment: Sorry Dave, I'm not sure what you mean there?

Comment: The code compiled will be compliant with a 1.5 java runtime. You could drop it on a server with a 1.5 version of Java and it will run just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Sutty1000 - much appreciated. I thought this myself. Just needed someone to validate my own thinking.

Comment: @thonnor No problem, have the exact same issues here but we are stuck on Java 1.4 for one key application :( painful.

Comment: @Sutty1000 - Just to clarify, did your apps build & run ok using a higher JDK than your runtime & with the Eclipse JDK Compliance set to 1.4 ?

Comment: @thonnor yes, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

It means the byte code that is generated from your source code will be compliant to the 1.5 JRE.

The syntax highlighter will not allow you to do things that were new to 1.6, 1.7 such as switching on strings.

Comment: Thanks James. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Developing with a JDK higher than the target platform is in principle possible, using the "compliance settings" and/or target version switches with javac.

Its however not practically feasible for doing real development, as nothing will prevent/warn you from using the API's present in your installed JDK but not in the target platform.

If, for example you develop for java 1.4 using an installed 1.5, while the compiler will not let you use autoboxing (which was introduced in 1.5), but it will happily let you use (for example) Integer.valueOf(int). Which is not present in 1.4.